# CSV comparison of Windows Services

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, service

I'm fairly new to Powershell and I'm stuck with this portion of a much larger script. I need to pull all Windows Services and compare them to see if their Startup Type of Status has changed. If there were any changes, I need to count them so I can put that value in the body of an e-mail. Also, I need to attach an HTML report showing the previous and current state of the Windows services that changed.

What I've done is the following:

That piece of code generates a CSV file showing the current state of the services.

```
Get-Service | Select-Object -Property Name,DisplayName,StartType,ServiceType,Status | Export-Csv -Path "C:\logs\after.csv"
```

Then i declare two variables, one for the current state, another one for the "template", the desired state of all Windows Services.

```
$before = Import-Csv -Path "C:\logs\before.csv"
$after = Import-Csv -Path "C:\logs\after.csv"
```

Then, i compare both of them, parsing only those service that've changed and generate a CSS styled HTML report based on that

```
Compare-Object $before $after -Property Name,DisplayName,StartType,ServiceType,Status | ConvertTo-html -Head $css | Set-Content "C:\logs\comparison.html"
```

This is what i get:

[image]

This is what it should look like:

[image]

Basically, i want to show the status of the latter CSV report in a new column after the Status column of the original CSV report. And I would also like to make a row count after that, so I can send an e-mail reporting HOW MANY services suffered any changes.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Group-Object` after `Compare-Object` and parse out the columns you need from that.

```
$before = Import-Csv -Path "C:\logs\before.csv"
$after  = Import-Csv -Path "C:\logs\after.csv"

# find the differences in the StartType and Status columns. Use -PassThru to be able to process further
$groups = Compare-Object -DifferenceObject $before -ReferenceObject $after -Property StartType, Status -PassThru | 
          Sort-Object Name | Group-Object Name

$result = foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $refGroup = $after | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $group.Name }
    # output an object with new StartType_* and  Status_* columns and capture that in variable $result
    $group.Group[0] | 
    Select-Object *, @{Name = 'StartType_Before'; Expression = {$_.StartType}},
                     @{Name = 'StartType_After'; Expression = {$refGroup.StartType}},
                     @{Name = 'Status_Before'; Expression = {$_.Status}},
                     @{Name = 'Status_After'; Expression = {$refGroup.Status}} -ExcludeProperty StartType,Status, SideIndicator
}

# now convert the $result to HTML and add a summary line with the number of services that have changed
$result | ConvertTo-Html -Head $css -PostContent "<br />Services affected: $($result.Count)" | 
          Set-Content "C:\logs\comparison.html"
```

If you also want output in the console do:

```
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

---

Of course it is also possible to not use `Compare-Object` and do like below (will be slower, but easier to understand I guess):

```
$before = Import-Csv -Path "C:\logs\before.csv"
$after  = Import-Csv -Path "C:\logs\after.csv"

$result = foreach ($item in $before) {
    $diff = $after | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $item.Name -and 
                                   ($_.StartType -ne $item.StartType -or $_.Status -ne $item.Status) }
    if ($diff) {
        $item | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'StartType_Before'; Expression = {$item.StartType}},
                                 @{Name = 'StartType_After'; Expression = {$diff.StartType}},
                                 @{Name = 'Status_Before'; Expression = {$item.Status}},
                                 @{Name = 'Status_After'; Expression = {$diff.Status}} -ExcludeProperty StartType,Status
    }
}

# output to console
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# convert to HTML
$result | ConvertTo-Html -Head $css -PostContent "<br />Services affected: $($result.Count)" | 
          Set-Content "C:\logs\comparison.html"
```

Output on screen will look something like

```
Name            DisplayName                                             ServiceType     StartType_Before StartType_After Status_Before Status_After
----            -----------                                             -----------     ---------------- --------------- ------------- ------------
AarSvc_8246b1   Agent Activation Runtime_8246b1                         224             Manual           Automatic       Stopped       Stopped     
AdobeARMservice Adobe Acrobat Update Service                            Win32OwnProcess Automatic        Automatic       Running       Stopped     
ALG             Application Layer Gateway Service                       Win32OwnProcess Manual           Automatic       Stopped       Stopped     
WdNisSvc        Microsoft Defender Antivirus Network Inspection Service Win32OwnProcess Manual           Manual          Running       Stopped
```

Comment: Theo, thank you so much! This has worked wonders. Sorry for being such a newbie, but how could I manage to do the same thing to the Start Type Property?

My end goal would be to do the same thing you've done on the Status Column to the Start Type column, i.e. having an Start Type_Before next to an Start Type_After column.

Once again, thank you so much.

Comment: @RubénAndrésGarcía Ah.. I missed that part. On mobile now, but I will put that in tomorrow.

Comment: @RubénAndrésGarcía Please try my edited answer

Comment: Theo, your solution worked wonders, thank you so much! I've already marked the question as solved/answered.

Is there another way I can upvote you?

Comment: Also, there's this last thing I'm asked to do and I can't wrap my head around it. I've worked my way through if's to make sure there's no mail being sent if there are no changes made to the Services (thanks to your invaluable help), between some other things, but this last  requirement is very difficult for me.

Now I'm also tasked with the following:
- Changing the cell colors if the values of the cols StartType_After and Status_After reflect any changes
- Changing the color of the entire row if one of the differences is an entirely new service.

Once again, thank you!

Comment: @RubénAndrésGarcía Well.. that's quite some extra requirement and involves html styling. I suggest you post a new question specific to coloring cells/rows conditionally in a Html table using powershell. I'll try to give you an answer, but I'm sure more people on this platform can help you out too.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too, maybe I could put some condition in place regarding CSS styling, I don't know.

Is there any way, however, to discriminate between the services which state or starttype has changed AND those that were non-existant before the current report?

I'll wait for your answer, though. I'm really, REALLY grateful!